# Content Query WebPart Error while executing web part: System.NullReferenceException:

Tags: 2010, 2013

I am trying to add the following content by query webpart programatically but I have the error below

```
#region Last updated documents
                            ContentByQueryWebPart cqwp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
                            cqwp.ContentTypeBeginsWithId = "0x0101008E49C3D400044AB3A2F1DD14073E74F6001D06D12572244BE3A11AAEE3ED60F576";
                            cqwp.WebUrl = SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                            cqwp.Title = "Last Updated Documents";                                
                            string query = @"<OrderBy> "+
                                                "<FieldRef Name='Modified'  Ascending='FALSE'/> "+
                                            "</OrderBy>";
                            cqwp.QueryOverride = query;
                            cqwp.ItemLimit = 10;
                            cqwp.ListsOverride =  "<Lists ServerTemplate='101'/>";
                            cqwp.WebsOverride = "<Webs Recursive='False' />";

                            cqwp.MainXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ContentQueryMain.xsl");
                            cqwp.HeaderXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl");
                            cqwp.ItemXslLink = SPUtility.ConcatUrls(SPContext.Current.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl");

                            cqwp.ViewFieldsOverride = @"<ViewFields> " +
                                                            "<FieldRef Name='DocIcon'/>"+
                                                            "<FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' />" +
                                                            "<FieldRef Name='ContentType'/> " +
                                                            "<FieldRef Name='Modified'/> " +
                                                            "<FieldRef Name='Editor'/> " + 
                                                        "</ViewFields>";                              

                            mgrPageManager.AddWebPart(cqwp, "Footer", 0);
                            mgrPageManager.SaveChanges(cqwp);
                        #endregion




Error while executing web part: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.AddViewFieldsFromOverride()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.buildCrossListQueryInfo()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.IssueQuery()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls.ContentByQueryWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String viewPath)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean bDeferExecuteTransform)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wild, or not so wild, guess:

Your `<FieldRef Name='Modified By' Nullable='True' Type='Text'/>` could be the cause of the problem. SharePoints internal column names do not ever contain blanks.

I think the internal or static name is actually `Editor`

EDIT:
Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart.commonviewfields.aspx) the correct format for this parameter is:

```
"Title,Text;ID,Counter;Editor,User"
```

So, Column name, Type;

Comment: good eye, testing now

Comment: that didnt fix the issue.

Comment: Editor is not ot type text either, just leave out the types.

Comment: I thought the same, I removed all types, testing now.

Comment: Lingdgren, see my edited code, still the same problem

Comment: Found some msdn stuff for you